# Pseudo-classe CSS :nth-of-type()

Tags: css

Veja só..

```css
div .p:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
DIV 1
<div div="div1">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
</div>

DIV 2
<div id="div2">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, eu quero selecionar o segundo elemento da classe P(.p) filha de um pai(div), e não é o que resulta.. 
se eu fizer o uso de `nth-of-type(1`) ele funciona, que para mim traduzido seria, selecionar o primeiro elemento do tipo paragrafo filho de um pai(div). Mas porquê `nth-of-type(2)` não vai lá para o quarto parágrafo de ambas as divs, dando o efeito negrito..

Comment: Se eu escreve-se, `.p:nth-of-type(2)` eu estou querendo acessar o elemento cuja classe é .p, cuja é filha de um pai( que no caso é uma div ), não seria essa a interpretação? Ou seja, selecionar o segundo elemento da classe(.p), e como eu indiquei que o pai é a div, logo na minha visão, ambas as divs teriam que ter o 4° parágrafo negritados.

Comment: @AlexandreC.Caus está pseudo-class não funciona da maneira que você está buscando, de uma olhada aqui nessa [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type), o que você parece procurar é [isso: nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Para funcionar com o :nth-of-type você teria que mover o <p class="p">p4</p> para cima dos ps, mas no teu caso seria melhor usar o :nth-child mesmo

Comment: Uma dúvida, vale apena usar este nth-of-type, para eu selecionar 9 parágrafos, dentro de uma div com 15 parágrafos, ou seria melhor eu identificar por IDS e aplicar direto na ID o efeito? Digo melhor, no termo de velocidade, porquê é mais simples aplicar uma ID e colocar um estilo nela, estou pensando que atrasa mais usando pseudo-seletor, navegador tem que pensar mais.. alguem tem algum comentário a respeito disso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem como fazer usando combinadores:

```css
/*Seleciona a segunda ocorrência do elemento com a classe .p dentro de uma div */
div > .p ~ .p {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: blue;
}

/*Seleciona a terceira ocorrência do elemento com a classe .p dentro de uma div */
div > .p ~ .p ~ .p {
   font-weight: bold;
   color: green;
}
```

```html
DIV1
<div div="div1">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
</div>

DIV 2
<div id="div2">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
  <p class="p">p5</p>
</div>
```

Cada repetição da classe separada pelo combinador `~` significa um nível na classe que quer escolher.

Seletores nível 3:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

**EDIT:**

Como citei no comentário enquanto ainda não temos [seletores de nível 4](http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/) a saída seria usar JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/xL9qw5od/

Comment: Quem sabe sabe. rs. Muito show esse seletor, nem sabia que isso existia. Parabéns Edi. Gomes já ganhou um voto meu.

Comment: Entendo, ele define a partir de qual nível será aplicado o estilo.. logo 5 parágrafos, com o 2° e 3° e 5° com a classe `.p`, e eu quisesse apenas aplicar na segundo ocorrência da classe `.p`, usando deste método aplicará no 3° parágrafo quanto no 5° parágrafo usando `div > .p ~ .p.`
veja -> http://jsfiddle.net/z4WhX/.

Comment: Então você quer aplicar somente no 3º?

Comment: Quero aplicar na segunda ocorrência da classe `.p` dentro de uma div por exemplo.. Dentro dessa divs, poderiam ter vários parágrafos, não necessariamente todos com a classe `.p`.

Comment: Então, no caso como ainda não temos seletores de nível 4 veja: http://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/ a saída seria fazer com JQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/xL9qw5od/

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer selecionar "filhos" basta usar "+":

Exemplo

```css
div p:first-child + p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
DIV 1
<div div="div1">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
</div>

DIV 2
<div id="div2">
  <p class="p">p1</p>
  <p>p2</p>
  <p>p3</p>
  <p class="p">p4</p>
</div>
```

Veja que uso o :first-child para referenciar ao primeiro

e '+ p' para referenciar o próximo, sempre que quiser um próximo, acrescente '+ p'.

Não posso dizer que esta é a melhor maneira, mas se entendi bem, isso funciona.